# How hoisting concept actually works with functions and variables in javascript

Tags: javascript, hoisting

What the difference between Creation Phase and Execution phase in hoisted variables and functions. also how Execution Context is working at this case in javascript console

Refer to this example :

```
b();
console.log(a);

var a = 'Hello World';

function b() {
    console.log('Called b!');
}
```

**Output:**

```
Called b!
undefined
```

How can you explain this scenario:

in function case it returns **Called b!**

in variable case it returns **undefined**

Comment: It's not clear what is not clear in that code. `Called b!` is printed because you printed exactly that. `undefined` is printed because the `a` variable is not initialised at that point.

Comment: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation --- here is where the function declaration runtime semantics is explained.

Comment: @zerkms why at function case it reruns called b! even that i declared my function after calling it and in variable case it return undefined when the variable is actually not created yet.
how execution context is working in runtime?

Comment: Check the link to the standard, it explains how the function declaration is handled in runtime.

Comment: also why it doesn't return `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined` when printing a.

Comment: Because `a` is declared (it's just not initialised).

Comment: yes it declared but after `console.log(a)` statement 

if we Suppose execution context works line by line it shouldn't print `undefined`

actually it should return runtime error.

Comment: Given you know the "hoisting" term, is it safe to assume you checked something about what it means? I am asking because it was explained million times in details, and there is really no reason to do it again, unless you have any particular problem.

Comment: "yes it declared but after" --- it's hoisted, so the declaration is made before any other statement is executed.

Comment: you are right it's not safe to assume that, but I asked because I am trying to understand how it's actually working in execution context.

Comment: `var a` declaration is made before any other statement in your code. By the moment it reaches the second line - it's declared but uninitialised.

Comment: in this case when javascript console executed these lines of code first it will setup location in memory for variable `a` but it will not set the assigned value until it reaches this line of code `var a = 'Hello World';`

Comment: and because i print it before assignment statement it will be `undefined`

Comment: @Oghli Yes, that's what happens

Comment: I wouldn't speak of that in terms of "location in memory" (since the standard does not have a notion of "memory" at all). But yes, it "sets up" a binding.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks it really helped me.
can you explain how the function is created and executed in runtime

Comment: @Oghli the declaration process is explained in the second link. Execution is scattered over few places. Do you really need to know that in such details? Just read the whole standard then ;-)